# Size of buffered input in C

Tags: c, linux, posix, cat

I'm writing a simple clone of GNU coreutils in order to better understand the GNU/Linux system and POSIX systems in general. In my "cat" clone, I used `fseek()` and `ftell()` to calculate the size of an input buffer `size` (no support for `stdin`), and allocate this to a buffer. I would then `fread()` `size` bytes from stream `fp` into the buffer `buff`, which I would print to `stdout`.
Here's a snippet of code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE* stream = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long sz = ftell(stream);
    rewind(stream);
    char* buf = malloc(sz);
    fread(buf, sz, 1, stream);
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

This implementation has two major problems:

1. If the size in bytes of a stream is greater than the largest value the integer data type you use to hold it (`int`, `size_t`) the value will overflow and you will be left with an incorrect number. For the most part, this is solved by using a `size_t` rather than an `int` as `size_t` is 64 bit and can thus handle larger numbers - but ultimately, it can't handle arbitrarily sized files without crashing and burning.
2. With a very large file (several gigabytes) the memory allocated would be too large and the kernel would send a SIGKILL for the sake of freeing up major amounts of resources (in my case). This would mean the program would be wholly unable to handle very large files and would not be very efficient.

I would rather not use mmap because it adds to the complexity of the program - I'm trying to keep the program as simple as possible. I've decided to buffer the input, ie. `fread()` x bytes, print them to `stdout`, free the memory and rinse and repeat until the entire file has been printed.

My question is, how large should `x` be? Is there a standard for how many bytes should be read? Too large a number and the program becomes incredibly memory-intensive, too little a number and the program would call fread() far too many times, slowing it down as a whole. How many bytes should be read in one go for the best compromise of speed and resource usage?

Comment: I would say it depends on the machine you are running...

Comment: Welcome to SO. `ftell` returns `long`, not `int`. Also if you think about `cat` you are probably dealing about text files. Be aware that `\n` might get converted to `\r\n` if you open the file in text mode.

Comment: Why `\r\n`? Isn't that the line break for Windows? I'm on Linux, I intend for my coreutils clone only to be used on unix-like systems.

Comment: I've just replaced the `size_t` with `long`, thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, if you don't care about portability then it doesn't matter.

Comment: When you do need to find the size of a disk file (although here you certainly do *not* need to do that!), and if you're not worried about portability to non-Unixy systems, then `stat` or `fstat` is usually a much, much better choice.  (See the `st_size` field.)

Comment: You might also want to consider using `open`/`read`/`write`/`close`, rather than `fopen`/`fread`/`fwrite`/`fclose`.

Comment: You almost never need to know the size of a file.  If you think you do, think again.

Comment: I tried using `stat` and `fstat`, but I always ended up getting 0 as the result, even when the actual stat command (in bash, NOT the C POSIX function). I had a similar problem with mmap. It just seemed like fopen() and fread() were just less likely to fail. @SteveSummit

Comment: @oxibts What kind of system are you using?  Straight Unix, straight Linux, MacOS, Linux emulation under Windows?  If `stat` and `fstat` aren't reliable for you, that's a problem you're going to have to track down and resolve.  One issue might be conflicting ideas of whether file sizes (aka `off_t` values) are 32 or 64 bits.  In 32-bit Linux, there's a strange kludge involving `FILE_OFFSET_BITS` that controls this.

Comment: Why do you want to alloc and free the memory? Just use a static buffer, for such a simple program it is probably the best way. No need for the complexity of `malloc()`

Comment: On Linux there is also `copy_file_range()`

Comment: On POSIX systems there's also `ftello` and `fseeko` that return/take arguments of type `off_t`, which is the correct type to use for file offset.

But like already mentioned, for a cat clone you don't need that. Just have a loop around a suitable buffer size.

Answer (score 4):

Two things -- the underlying *nix file system will employ some pretty sophisticated buffering, so not there is no point in being too clever about it in your implementation.

Just allocate a decent size buffer (some multiple of 4K) and keep reusing it by looping round "fread" and "print".
You will to capture the number of bytes actually read by fread as the last read will be smaller than the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

When <s>in rome</s> building a coreutils clone, do as <s>the romans</s> GNU coreutils does (or at least have a look at how they do it).

[According to this](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/02fc0e3f683f3858513c7c7226d30503e7f7ec97/src/cat.c#L718), the block size used by GNU cat is defined by the maximum block size of the input file handle and the output file handle reported by `stat()`/`fstat()`, [but at minumum 128 kiB](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/00ea4bacf6063ccc125209d5186f8f2382c6f0d4/src/ioblksize.h#L77) (this value, according to comments, is based on benchmarks).

Comment: *the block size used by GNU cat...*  `cat` is a very limited use case - stream through the file contents once.  Using such a large buffer for a general-purpose `FILE` buffer would lead to serious read amplification - every time `fseek()` is called, the next read operation will read data to fill the entire buffer.